# Labels ValueFormat is ignored

Tags: c#, formatting, teechart

How can I change the decimal separator for a Steema TeeChart Axis Label to be `.` instead of a `,`?

I checked the tutorial which stated that:

> Label formats  You may apply all standard number and date formats to
>   Axis labels. The Axis page, Labels section contains the field "Values
>   format". If your data is datetime the field name changes to "Date time
>   format". At runtime use:
>
> ```
> [C#.Net] tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.ValueFormat = "#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)";
> ```

I tried this but it seems to be ignored when I use custom `ValueFormats`. If I use `C` for instance a currency is attached, and if I use `0.#` I get one decimal, but the separator is still a `,`.

I can listen to the `m_Chart.GetAxisLabel` and I see that the ValueFormat is the same as the one I entered, and the `e.LabelText` is `0,00`. I can then modify the `e.LabelText` to be "0.00" instead. However, I would much rather use a Format specifier for this.

Is it possible to change a format specifier for a chart to use `.` instead of `,` when displaying numbers?

A short example of what I am doing:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Line line = new Line();
    Random random = new Random();

    //line.Add(101, 1000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        line.Add(i, random.Next(100)/100.0f);
    }

    line.XValues.DateTime = false;
    m_Chart.Series.Add(line);

    m_Chart.Legend.Visible = false;
    m_Chart.Aspect.View3D = false;
    m_Chart.Axes.Left.Labels.ValueFormat = "# ##0.00";

    // I _can_ use this, but rather not.
    //m_Chart.GetAxisLabel += OnGetAxisLabel;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a .NET Framework issue to me. You could try setting the [NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator(v=vs.110).aspx). For example, code below does it for me.

```
  System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Name, true);
  ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
  System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
```